# Exchange 2010 is trying to relay messages for delivery

Tags: smtp, exchange-2010

I am using Exchange 2010 on premises. I am in the process of setting up a SMTP proxy that will receive all messages coming into the office, log them, then forward them to my exchange server for local delivery.

I am running into a problem with messages that contain a To or CC for users on non-company domains. When the message flows through the proxy, exchange thinks that the messages is being delivered to it for relay and gives a 550 unable to relay. I can't find where to specify that a certain IP or port is used for local delivery only and not relay.

As far as I can tell, the proxy is executing the same SMTP commands that a direct inbound message would be. The only difference is a local private IP is specifying the commands, and not a random mail server with a public IP.

Comment: Your SMTP proxy is trying to relay through Exchange. Exchange doesn't know your proxy from any other SMTP server. When Exchange sees the CC or BCC for the external recipients it's telling you that it won't relay email for domains that it's not authoritative for. What your SMTP proxy is asking it to do is the definition of relaying. You need to configure Exchange to allow the proxy to relay through it.

Comment: I have inbound email going through the proxy before hitting exchange. I do not want exchange to relay, that would be an open relay. I want exchange to deliver the inbound messages to it's local users and ignore the rest. It is not ignoring the rest, it is trying to relay them.

Comment: Your proxy should have recipient recognition, usually a list it maintains or syncs with your Exchange server, that will drop any email destined for an invalid recipient that isn't on that list at the proxy itself before trying to even interact with the Exchange server.  By the way, the generally accepted term is "SMTP or Email Gateway" or "Email Smarthost" not proxy, but I digress.  Is this homebrewed or 3rd party?

Comment: I am trying to using OpaqueMail, and they call it an SMTP / POP / IMAP Proxy. I realize now that there are no examples of logging inbound SMTP messages and I think I know what is happening now. I'll post back when I confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring a relay connector to allow the proxy SMTP server to relay through Exchange doesn't make Exchange an open relay. Many organizations configure and use relay connectors in Exchange for applications, web servers, log servers, etc.

But I'm not really understanding the problem. Why is the SMTP proxy trying to send email to Exchange for the non-local addresses? It should only be sending the email to the local addresses. The non-local recipients are handled by their own inbound email servers. The SMTP proxy shouldn't be addressing the email to anyone but the local recipients, where those recipient addresses are in the TO field.

When a sender sends an email to a recipient and CC's and/or BCC's additional recipients, an individual copy of the message is created for each recipient and their address is placed in the TO field. The sending server then sends each copy of the message to the respective recipients email server. The recipient server delivers the email to the recipient addressed in the TO field and ignores the recipients in the CC and/or BCC fields. So why is the SMTP proxy trying to send the email to the addresses in the CC and/or BCC fields to begin with? It should only be sending the message to the recipient in the TO field, which should only be local recipients. In the case where multiple local recipients are in the CC and/or BCC field, the SMTP proxy should be receiving an independent copy of the message for each local recipient from the senders email server.

Comment: I think you are on the right path, and I think I understand what may be going on now. When the message hits the proxy, it is getting the RCPT To: field specified for my local user only. The proxy is then writing the email contents to an EML file, then trying to forward that message to exchange.

I bet the proxy is re-reading the EML file and coming up with it's own list of "to" addresses that includes all users, even the ones outside my network, and trying to relay them all through exchange.

Comment: That sounds like what's happening. I think you're on the right track. Now to figure out how to fix it.